# How to stop Unity love handles on onscreen keybord

Tags: unity, multi-touch, onboard

I have a Dell XPS12 - the one that converts into a tablet.

When typing with onboard [default onscreen keyboard], sometimes 3 fingers will be touching the screen at the same time. This launches the love handles which then stuff up the typing.

I really do love the 3 finger move and resize stuff though, is there a way to disable this just for the one program? I can't seem to find anything for this in ccsm - but maybe I just missed it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!